# Text is an invalid XmlNodeType when running Visual Studio tests

Tags: visual-studio-2017, mstest

I have been creating test automation using Visual Studio Test. My Code is stored on Visual Studio Online and it uses GitHub to store the source code.

The problem is as of this morning, I started seeing the error "'Text' is an invalid XmlNodeType' when I try to run my tests from Visual Studio' Test Explorer.

I have been adding new test methods to the source and updating the test.runsettings file with additional parameters. The test.runsettings file is getting large, as I have about 152 tests.

I can't post the runsettings file, as it contains server names ad infinitum.
And the server tests code is standardized MS unit tests.

Has anyone seen this issue pop up?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer as to why the project can't be run in Visual Studio 2017, however I found a workaround. I'm using VSTest.Console.exe on the command line to test my automation.

```
vstest.console.exe myTests.dll /Settings:test.runsettings /Tests:TestMethod1 /Diag:Info.txt
```

Comment: In addition, the name of the TestContext must precisely match the TestContext class.

Comment: In addition, the test.runsettings file had word-wrapped.